# Rota sem proteção de token pedindo token

Tags: laravel, jwt

Estou tentando cadastrar um novo usuario que não está na rota protegida por middleware token jwt, mas estou recebendo o return.

```
{
    "error": "The token could not be parsed from the request"
}
```

Segue arquivo routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function(){
    Route::resource('tipoDespesa', 'TipoDespesaController');
    Route::resource('mudarTexto', 'MudarTextoController');

    // Usuario
    // Route::get('user', 'PessoaController@show');
    // Route::put('user', 'PessoaController@update');
    // Route::delete('user', 'PessoaController@destroy');

    Route::resource('conta', 'ContaController');
    Route::resource('categoria-despesa', 'CategoriaDespesaController');
    Route::put('conta/ativar/{id}', 'ContaController@ativar');
    Route::get('auth/me', 'AuthController@me');
});

Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('auth/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('auth/refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('new/user', 'PessoaController@store');
```

Postman

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PessoaController@store
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não coloque imagem, coloque o código completo desse controller

Comment: Nunca faça `$usuario->all()` quando for ainda filtrar, faça `$usuario->where('','')->get()` ou  `$usuario->where('','')->count()`, para que o filtro seja escrito na SQL e executado retornando do banco de dados só o que necessita

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Herick,

Vi que a rota que está chamando no Postman é

Route::post('new/user', 'PessoaController@store');

E como usa o método POST o Laravel por definição exige um token para evitar Cross Site Request Forgery, veja na documentação do link abaixo que dentro de um formulário HTML utilizamos o {{ csrf_field() }} para criar um campo "hidden" com esse token gerado automaticamente pelo PHP (Server side).

Documentação:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-introduction

O erro que está aparecendo para você não tem referência com o JWT e sim com o verbo POST, dá para mudar para GET e passar todos os dados pela URL mas isso não é uma boa ideia. O principio é de que se vai criar um novo usuário você já deve estar logado ou já estar na aplicação, se quer fazer através de uma API para consumir um serviço terá que autenticar primeiro

Espero que não tenha ficado muito confuso, mas dá uma lida na documentação ou me dá um toque por aqui e te ajudamos.

Abc